# Autocomplete for jupyter R kernel inside VSCode does not work

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter

I have been using Jupyter Notebooks on vscode and have noticed that code autocompletion (via tab) doesn't work at all when I use an R kernel. It works just fine when I use a python kernel, and also works ok for .py files within vscode. I couldn't find any info online - does anyone have a solution for this (if there is one)?

Comment: I have noticed the same issue, but have no solution for it.

Comment: Same here. Quite frustrating.